# Translate an specific SQL query to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I need your help because I'm trying to translate a very specific SQL query to Linq but I can't do it by myself because of an ISNULL clause that I don't know how to put it in LINQ. Here is the SQL query:

```
select f.fId as alias1, f.fDate, f.IniHour, f.EndHour, f.Cap, f.Ocup
  , isnull(
    (select o.Cap - o.Ocup
     from table2 o
     left outer join table3 r on o.id = r.id 
     where o.fId=f.id and r.fieldI = @value)
   , 1) as alias2 
from table1 f
inner join table4 t on f.id=t.id
and f.fDate+cast(fIniHour as datetime) > Dateadd(Hour,2,Getdate())
order by f.fDate,f.IniHour
```

The problem is how to put the ISNULL in the Select clause in the Linq query. Could you, please, help me with this issue?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please show the effort you tried. If the IsNull is the problem please show the joins and nested selects and such. We can help with the rest

Comment: BTW, why `left outer join` in the inner quey? NULL is anyway converted to 1 by your ISNULL.

Comment: Also you need to show how you are using EF(Mappings, collections...), But in a more general way == null in Linq will do a proper is null.

Comment: But how could I put that isnull clause inside a linq query? Because it's put inside the select clause